# ActionScript3: How to "offset" playing of sound object(with multiple objects playing at same time)

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, action, progress

I want to make a program where you arrange sound samples. A cursor plays the sound it sweeps over and there can be many sound samples played at once. I want the user to be able to change/intterupt the playing(aka cursor progress) with a mouse click(similar to a progress bar).

I understand there are some ways of playing multiple sounds files at once, but thats not the problem. I wonder how I can play a sound sample from an offset when a click interrupt is generated.

Which AS3 class should I look at? Any other tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Sound.play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) supplying the offset in milliseconds. You should first calculate the offset by measuring mouse position vs the progress bar, then stop the sound if it's playing, then call `theSound.play(yourOffset)` and you should be set.

Comment: It wont play immediately from the offset location. The sound must have cached or downloaded till the offset point.

Comment: @SameerJain Sure, but OP didn't state if the sound is external to SWF. Also loading a sound is never mentioned in the question, so the assumption that sound is fully loaded is default.

Comment: I assumed otherway :)